# C socket programming: calling recv() changes my socket file descriptor?

Tags: c, unix, sockets, client-server, recv

Hey all, I have this strange problem with recv(). I'm programming client/server where client send() a message (a structure to be exact) and server recv() it. I am also working with multiple sockets and select().

```
while(1)
{
    readset = info->read_set;
    info->copy_set = info->read_set;

    timeout.tv_sec = 1; 
    timeout.tv_usec = 0; // 0.5 seconds

    ready = select(info->max_fd+1, &readset, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

    if (ready == -1)
    {
        printf("S: ERROR: select(): %s\nEXITING...", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (ready == 0)
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("S: oh finally you have contacted me!\n");
        for(i = 0; i < (info->max_fd+1); i++)
        {

            if(FD_ISSET(i, &readset)) //this is where problem begins
            {
                printf("S: %i is set\n", i);
                printf("S: we talking about socket %i son\n", i);  // i = 4
                num_bytes = recv(i, &msg, MAX_MSG_BYTE, 0);
                printf("S: number of bytes recieved in socket %i is %i\n", i, num_bytes); // prints out i = 0 what??

                if (num_bytes == 0)
                {
                    printf("S: socket has been closed\n");
                    break;
                }
                else if (num_bytes == -1)
                {
                    printf("S: ERROR recv: %d %s \n", i, strerror(errno));
                    continue;
                }
                else                    
                {
                    handle_request(arg, &msg);
                    printf("S: msg says %s\n", msg->_payload);
                }
            } // if (FD_ISSET(i, &readset)
            else
                printf("S:  %i is not set\n", i);
        } // for (i = 0; i < maxfd+1; i++) to check sockets for msg
    } // if (ready == -1)   

    info->read_set = info->copy_set;
    printf("S: copied\n");

}
```

the problem I have is that in `read_set`, 0~3 aren't set and 4 is. That is fine. But when i call `recv()`, `i` suddently becomes 0. Why is that? It doesn't make sense to me why `recv()` would take an socket file descriptor number and modify to another number. Is that normal? Am I missing something?

```
S:  0 is not set
S:  1 is not set
S:  2 is not set
S:  3 is not set
S: 4 is set
S: we talking about socket 4 son
S: i is strangely or unstrangely 0
S: number of bytes recieved in socket 0 is 40
```

That's what it prints out.

Answer (score 2):

`recv` cannot modify its first argument, since it is taken by value.

You don't show where you've declared `msg` or `i`, but based on this line

```
printf("S: msg says %s\n", msg->_payload);
```

Where you use the `->` operator on `msg`, I assume it's probably like this:

```
struct somestruct* msg = malloc(sizeof(struct somestruct));
int i;
```

Then you do this:

```
num_bytes = recv(i, &msg, MAX_MSG_BYTE, 0);
```

Note that `msg` is *already* a pointer, so `&msg` is a *pointer to the pointer*.

What this will then do is receive data and try to store it in the place where the `msg` *pointer* itself is, not the place that `msg` points *to*. Typically, pointers are only 4 bytes long, so this will overflow the storage if you receive more than four bytes. If `i` is declared on the stack after `msg`, then it is likely that it is being overwritten by this overflow, and it happens to get overwritten by all zero bytes from the received packet.

Since `msg` is already a pointer, change your receive line to eliminate the superfluous indirection:

```
num_bytes = recv(i, msg, MAX_MSG_BYTE, 0);
```

Similarly, you may want to consider making the same change to the line

```
handle_request(arg, &msg)
```

if the `handle_request` function is not really expecting a pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: This seems pretty likely to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be that `sizeof(msg) < MAX_MSG_BYTE` and when `recv` overflows `msg` it trashes `i`.